# Nodemailer e-mail send not working in Node.js

Tags: node.js, nodemailer, google-account

I tried to send e-mail using Node.js Nodemailer but it is not working. I do not know how to set up it properly. I have used below code but it is not working and I'm getting error. I am new to Nodemailer, so I'm not able to find out the mistake.

**Allow less secure apps: ON**

[image: Less secure apps access]

What do I need to do from google account? Please help anyone to find a solution.

**app.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const app = express();

// View engine setup
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// Static folder
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
    defaultLayout: false,
}));

//app.locals.layout = false;
 
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('contact');
});

app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
    const output = `
    <p>You have a new contact request</p>
    <h3>Contact Details</h3>
    <ul>  
      <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
      <li>Company: ${req.body.company}</li>
      <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
      <li>Phone: ${req.body.phone}</li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Message</h3>
    <p>${req.body.message}</p>
  `;

    // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'mail.madepartooty.com',
        port: 587,
        secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
        auth: {
            user: 'myemail@gmail.com', // generated ethereal user
            pass: 'test123' // generated ethereal password
        },
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    });

    // setup email data with unicode symbols
    let mailOptions = {
        from: '"Nodemailer Contact" <myemail@gmail.com>', // sender address
        to: 'toemail@gmail.com', // list of receivers
        subject: 'Node Contact Request', // Subject line
        text: 'Hello world?', // plain text body
        html: output // html body
    };

    // send mail with defined transport object
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
        console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
        res.render('contact', { msg: 'Email has been sent' });
    });
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server started...'));
```

**Error:**

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 157.245.154.37:587
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ECONNECTION',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '157.245.154.37',
  port: 587,
  command: 'CONN'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following

app.js

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var tech = require('./external.js');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
 service: 'Gmail',
 auth: {
        user: tech.senderUsername,
        pass: tech.senderPassword
    }
});

const mailOptions = {
  from: tech.senderUsername, // sender address
  to: tech.reciverUsername, // list of receivers
  subject: 'Subject of your email', // Subject line
  html: '<p>Enter your message here.</p>'// plain text body
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
   if(err)
     console.log(err)
   else
     console.log(info);
});
```

**Note :**

You may also need to follow these steps while using google account

Enable the settings to allow less secure apps for the Gmail account that you are using.
Here is the link: [Google Less Secure Apps](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin/signinchooser?service=accountsettings&passive=1209600&osid=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmyaccount.google.com%2Flesssecureapps&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fmyaccount.google.com%2Flesssecureapps&emr=1&mrp=security&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin)

Allow access for "Display Unlock captcha option" (Allow access to your Google account)
Here is the link: [Google Unlock Captcha](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin/signinchooser?passive=1209600&continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FDisplayUnlockCaptcha&followup=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FDisplayUnlockCaptcha&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin)

For more info, you can go through [sendMailUsingNodemailer](https://github.com/sureshmangs/Node.js-Stuff/tree/master/sendMailUsingNodemailer)

Answer (score 0):

This is caused when your request response is not received in given time (by timeout request module option). You can set the [timeout](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback) of your request in order to correctly execute your request and get response of this.

You can also build an error handler by this way :

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (err, origin) => {
  
});
```

Comment: Where i want to check this?

Comment: Got the answer.

Comment: process.on put in, on your code server side index.js maybe or other. The file built at server start