# Reset password link via nodemailer is not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, email, nodemailer

This is my React code =

```
const nodeMailer = require("nodemailer");

const defaultEmailData = { from: "noreply@react.com" };

exports.sendEmail = emailData => {
  const transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    requireTLS: true,
    auth: {
      user: "abc@gmail.com",
      pass: "abc"
    }
  });
  return (transporter.sendMail(emailData).then(info => console.log(Message sent: $ {
    info.response
  })).catch(err => console.log(Problem sending email: $ {
    err
  })));
};
```

There is a link on my website for users, who forgot their login passwords, they can click on the link for a reset password link to be sent to them with a link in the body of the email that will let them reset their passwords.

After I clicked on the reset password button, a message popped up that email has been sent to my email address which I must follow the instructions to reset my password. Even though I didn't get any email about this, my database was updated with the reset password link. Thank you.

Comment: It looks line the error happens not in the code that you add here.
Please, invest a little time into formating.

Comment: Your last `console.log` isn't logging a string, any errors?

Comment: Hi Phix, I can't test console.log for my nodemailer code because there is no layout or code design when I open the file in Chrome browser. Or can you teach me how to test it? Thanks!

Comment: During the last days GMail servers were abused for sending a large amount of SPAM. Some providers even stopped accepting mails from GMail. Therefore if you miss some mails sent via GMail it may be possible that this is a side-effect of that SPAM campaign. Have you retested it now if it sill does not work?

Comment: Als keep in mind that a lot of mail virus scanners click on ever link included in a mail to see if it leads to malicious file. Therefore adding plain links that directly performs an action is a bad idea today.

Comment: Refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62739918/11398996

Comment: Hi Robert, I already checked in my spam folder and I think it is not related to the SPAM but is related to the code problem. Can you help me to debug it? Thanks!